# Why does one say "he's in class" and not "he's in the class"?

Tags: articles, usage

why does one say "he's in class" and not "he's in the class" ?   As 'class' is countable here, so in singular it needs an article.

Thank you.

Comment: It’s parallel to phrases like *at work* and *at school*. The statement, “I didn’t see Jim at school today” refers, essentially, to the instructional **setting** or **context**, rather than to a specific location. By contrast,  “I didn’t see Jim at **the** school today” refers (to a greater extent) to the **place**, the **building**.

Comment: In this case "he's in the class" can also mean that he is a member of the group of students assigned to a particular class. "he's in class" cannot have this meaning, it must mean that he attending the class at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, Paul, all clear now.